# Nexmo API & CFHttp POST

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp, vonage

I am trying to use CFHttp to POST to the Nexmo API.

[API documentation](https://www.nexmo.com/documentation/api/index.html#buy)

```
<cfhttp url="https://rest.nexmo.com/number/buy/" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="#api.key#" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_secret" value="#api.secret#" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="country" value="US" type="url">
    <cfhttpparam name="msisdn" value="11234567890" type="url">
</cfhttp>
```

I get a status 420 (wrong parameters) when running this.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example in PHP: [API](https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib/blob/master/NexmoAccount.php)

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Could it be that its recognizing that your requested isdn is invalid?

Comment: @BenKoshy I have checked that everything being passed is valid. I just changed the number before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API documentation it appears to me that they are expecting the fields to be form values.  Here is an excerpt from [the documentation here](https://www.nexmo.com/documentation/#request):

> **HTTP Methods**
>
> All requests are submitted through the HTTP POST or GET method using UTF-8 encoding and URL encoded values.
>
> **Expected "Content-Type" for POST is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**, however we also support "application/json", "application/jsonrequest", "application/x-javascript", "text/json", "text/javascript", "text/x-javascript", "text/x-json" when posting parameters as a JSON object.

So try changing your code to the following:

```
<cfhttp url="https://rest.nexmo.com/number/buy/" method="post" charset="utf-8">
    <cfhttpparam name="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type="header">
    <cfhttpparam name="Accept" value="application/xml" type="header">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="#api.key#" type="formField">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_secret" value="#api.secret#" type="formField">
    <cfhttpparam name="country" value="US" type="formField">
    <cfhttpparam name="msisdn" value="11234567890" type="formField">
</cfhttp>
```

Note that I have the Accept header set to `application/xml`. According to the docs this could also be `application/json`. Change that value depending on what you want.

Comment: @Dre perhaps you need to include the character encoding as well. I have updated my code example.

Comment: Still no luck. I also tried `encoded="yes"` and it did not work.

Comment: @Dre I just noticed that the documentation also states **You must set the Accept HTTP header in your request**, so let me update my answer again.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. I can do `GET` requests all day long but `POST` is not cooperating.

Comment: Hmmm? Yeah it's just a matter of figuring out the format that they want. Have you found any examples in another language (PHP, etc.)?  That may help us.

Comment: @Dre I have added a `Content-Type` header to my example. Maybe we need to specify that as well?

Comment: @Dre I'm the developer evangelist at Nexmo, but I'm not that familiar with ColdFusion. If it's still not working (the current code in the answer looks good to me, as far as I can tell) - I can put together some example CURL calls that might be helpful.

Comment: I think that would be helpful. The above answer still does not work. Here is an example in PHP as requested. https://github.com/prawnsalad/Nexmo-PHP-lib/blob/master/NexmoAccount.php

Comment: I looked at the CURL examples from the docs to come up with this answer. I looked at that PHP example as well. The only thing I see them doing is setting the Content-Type and Accept headers which is what I tried to do here. What's odd to me is that the error returned is `420 wrong parameters`.  So I am assuming the communication/format portion is working.  The docs only mention the 2 parameters that he has included as required for this call. Could the key and/or secret be invalid? That should return a 401 error, right?

Comment: @Miguel-F Correct as to the 401. Is there any way to get a dump of the raw HTTP request? That would be very helpful.

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/kylejmhudson/4e8a6154da72972dce50 and report the result

Comment: @TimLytle I always use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to capture the raw HTTP traffic. The OP would need to install it on the ColdFusion server that is making the `cfhttp` request.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to formfield

```
<cfhttp url="https://rest.nexmo.com/number/buy/" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_key" value="#api.key#" type="FormField">
    <cfhttpparam name="api_secret" value="#api.secret#" type="FormField">
    <cfhttpparam name="country" value="US" type="FormField">
    <cfhttpparam name="msisdn" value="11234567890" type="FormField">
</cfhttp>
```

This docs are looking for a POST and your sending a combo post/get.  Based on what your sending over, your not sending the variables.  FormField will fix that.